# part of dependencies inherited form the parent's profile, some are not

Tags: maven

i have 4 dependencies with same scope  in a profile in the parent pom, and i am going to use it in the child project, but it turns out 3 of 4 dependencies are inherited, but one is not.

Parent pom is

```
<project>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>XXXX</groupId>
<artifactId>XX-XXX-XXXXX</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

  ........{not relevent}

<profiles>
    <profile>
       <id>another.profile</id>
       <activebydefault>true</activebydefault>
       <....a plugin dependency....>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>pro1</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>group1</groupId>
                <artifactId>arti1</artifactId>
                <version>${arti1.version}</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>group2</groupId>
                <artifactId>arti2</artifactId>
                <version>${arti2.version}</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>group3</groupId>
                <artifactId>arti3</artifactId>
                <version>${arti3.version}</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>group4</groupId>
                <artifactId>arti4</artifactId>
                <version>${arti4.version}</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
    </profile>
</project>
```

child pom is 
    
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>XXXXX</groupId>
<artifactId>XX-XXX-XXXXX</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

    <dependency>
         <groupId>group3</groupId>
         <artifactId>arti3</artifactId>
         <version>${arti3.version}</version>
         <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</project>
```

Then i am trying to use this profile in a child project, after i run `mvn -Ppro1 dependency:tree`, i cannot find the dependency for `<artifactId>arti3</artifactId>`

maven version 3.5.3

Comment: We do not have enough information to find the problem. It would be better if you show us an excerpt of the real pom. Is the profile pro1 activated? Are some dependencies also part of the child project?

Comment: @JFMeier hi, The real Pom is quite long and has a lot of unrelated content. But i can describe more. the Parent pom, contains two profiles, one is active by default which contains a plugin only, the other one is the one shown here. `pro1` will be actived by `mvn install -Ppro1`.  The last concern, `arti3` is also  part of child project with `provided` scope

Comment: Then it should appear in `dependency:list` with the scope `provided`. Could you check?